# Linear Combination of Random Normal Variables

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, moment-generating-function

In order to prove that the linear combination of two independent normal distributions(say Z=X+Y) is normal, i am using their MGFs to show that the linear combination also has a similar mgf. This works okay when Z = X+Y. But when Z=X-Y, i run into trouble :

E[$e^{tZ}$] = E[$e^{t(X-Y)}$] = E[$e^{tX}$]E[$e^{-tY}$]

Now i cannot put this as $M_{x}$(t) * $M_{y}$(t) because of the negative sign.

Comment: Let $W = -Y$. Then, $W$ is a normal $N(-\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2)$ random variable, independent of $X$, and $Z=X+W$. And away we go....

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

Let $W=−Y$. Then, $W$ is a normal $N(−μ_Y,σ^2_Y)$ random variable, independent of $X$, and $Z=X+W$. And away we go ... – Dilip Sarwate